# How to check call logs of my Android phone on my computer via internet

Tags: calls, data-monitoring, call-history

I looking for an app or something which can help to check my phone call logs on my computer, It should not involve USB cable, the app should work wirelessly..

is there any thing that is suitable for my requirement.?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Guide to Connecting Android Phone to PC through WiFi

**Download**

Go to Google Play to download AirMore on your Android phone.

**Go to AirMore Web**

Two Methods to get there:

**Method 1**: Open Chrome or Firefox browser on your PC. Manually type in the address: web.airmore.com
**Method 2**: Visit AirMore's product page. Click “Launch AirMore Web to Connect” button in the lower right.

**Connect Android device to PC**

**Step 1:** On your Android, find the AirMore app and open it. Tap the “Scan to connect” button.

**Step 2:** Scan the QR code displayed on the web or hit the device icon in Radar.

**Step 3:** On the condition that you connect devices in Radar, then click “Accept” option when a dialog comes out on your Android.

Note: For successful connection, your Android and PC are required to be in the same WiFi network environment.

In this way, without the need of USB cable, you can still connect Android to PC wirelessly.

As a cross-platform tool, AirMore enables you to transfer pictures, music, videos, apps, books, documents and files from Android to PC and vice versa.

Hope this helps!

Source:

https://airmore.com/help/android/connect-android-to-pc.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the Connect Me app.

Connect Me allows us to streamin all the media stored on the phone. You can even connect the camera on the phone with the desktop. As well as Airmore, Connect Me can also be used to make SMS and make phone calls without touching the phone screen. Measures of Connect Me use almost exactly Airmore, You can download Connect Me from Google Play Store. Connect Me works well on Windows, Linux, Mac and Chrome OS operating systems. This application is also able to send ringtones, copy paste with clipboard and also screenshots.